# How to Display only DatePart in Wpf DateTimepicker?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Dispalying Date in Wpf DateTimepicker Control in mm/dd/yyyy format without time. Date Property is binding from view Model.

Comment: Which exact control are you using? Have you tried using [`DatePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes I am using DatePicker.

Comment: Right - it's worth being precise when you ask the question (DateTimepicker != DatePicker). Now show how you're specifying the `DatePicker` in your XAML - what format you're using, if any, for example.

Comment: Mistake it's a **DateTimePicker** and I am using the property SelectedDatetime  type of DateTime &&
SelectedDateTime="{Binding SelectedDate,Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: So as I suggested, have you tried using a DatePicker, given that you're only interested in dates? I don't even see a `DateTimePicker` in the list of WPF controls. Please edit your question to link to the exact control you're using, and show the XAML *in the question*.

Comment: ya In DatePicker It's Working Fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While binding your datetimepicker to viewmodel property you can specify the date format like

```
{Binding DateTimeProperty, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  SelectedDateFormat property.

```
 SelectedDateFormat="Short"
```

or

can use custom string format.

```
{Binding YourDateProperty, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
```